# I'm trying to fetch data from sanity.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, sanity

I'm trying to get data from sanity but when I try to fetch its causing an error.
Here is my code ...

```
useEffect(() => {
  const query = '*[_type=="abouts"]';
  client.fetch(query).then((data) => setAbouts(data));
}, []);
```

ERROR:

```
request.js:28 Uncaught (in promise) ClientError {response: {…}, statusCode: 401, responseBody: '{\n  "message": "Session not found",\n "error": "Un…"errorCode": "SIO-401-ANF",\n  "statusCode": 401\n}', message: 'Unauthorized - Session not found', name: 'ClientError', …}response: {body: {…}, url: 'https://noa7mgdi.apicdn.sanity.io/v2022-09-06/data…y/production?query=*%5B_type%3D%3D%22abouts%22%5D', method: 'GET', headers: {…}, statusCode: 401, …}responseBody: "{\n  \"message\": \"Session not found\",\n  \"error\": \"Unauthorized\",\n  \"errorCode\": \"SIO-401-ANF\",\n  \"statusCode\": 401\n}"statusCode: 401message: "Unauthorized - Session not found"name: "ClientError"stack: "ClientError: Unauthorized - Session not found\n  
   at onResponse .onResponse (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3328:13 undefined)\n   
   at applyMiddleware .applyMiddleware (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:8680:23 undefined)\n   
   at onResponse .onResponse (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:7911:22 undefined)\n    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:7880:16\n   
   at onLoad .onLoad (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:8522:5 undefined)\n   
   at xhr.<computed> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:8385:5 undefined)"[[Prototype]]: BaseError
```

Comment: 401 is authentication  error. Check if you need to pass any API_KEY for tokens alng with request

Comment: If you're using a token, make sure it's the right one on your `env` variables or in your sanity `client`'s config if you're hard coding it (which you shouldn't). Another reason might be that your session timed out, in this case you could run `sanity logout` and then `sanity login` and try again. Also, make sure you're including the URL under CORS origin section on your sanity project.

Comment: @Ishraque Hi, did you find a solution ?I am also facing the same error.

Comment: Yes, my problem was solved. It was a typo in my query string.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. My problem was quotation marks around the token.

```
import SanityClient from "@sanity/client";
import ImageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";

export const client = SanityClient({
  projectId: "ux4eqs6a",
  dataset: "production",
  apiVersion: "2023-01-20",
  useCdn: true,
  token: "process.env.SANITY_AUTH_TOKEN", // ←←←←←←← HERE
});

const builder = ImageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```

I fixed it this way:

```
import SanityClient from "@sanity/client";
import ImageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";

export const client = SanityClient({
  projectId: "ux4eqs6a",
  dataset: "production",
  apiVersion: "2023-01-20",
  useCdn: true,
  token: process.env.SANITY_AUTH_TOKEN, // ←←←←←←← HERE
});

const builder = ImageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```

I also wrapped my token in the .env file in quotation marks. I would say it's either spelling or syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the token to "Authorization: Bearer "

**example token: "Authorization: Bearer " + process.env.SANITY_AUTH_TOKEN;**

```js
import SanityClient from "@sanity/client";
import ImageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";

export const client = SanityClient({
  projectId: "ux4eqs6a",
  dataset: "production",
  apiVersion: "2023-01-20",
  useCdn: true,
  token: "Authorization: Bearer " + process.env.SANITY_AUTH_TOKEN,
});

const builder = ImageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```